# how to add Shared filesystem on Metricbeat

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, metricbeat

I have Metricbeat on my server and it send system information to Elastic
My problem is that he send only the local filesystem and i want to have metric about the shared filesystem available on my server.

How can i added in the configuration of metricbeat to collect information about Shared FS also.
This is my file system.yml

```
# Module: system

- module: system
  period: 60s
  metricsets:
    - cpu
    - load
    - memory
    - network
    - process
    - process_summary
    - core
    - diskio
    - socket
  process.include_top_n:
    by_cpu: 5      # include top 5 processes by CPU
    by_memory: 5   # include top 5 processes by memory

- module: system
  period: 1m
  metricsets:
    - filesystem
    - fsstat
  processors:
  - drop_event.when.regexp:
      system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|host|lib)($|/)'

- module: system
  period: 15m
  metricsets:
    - uptime

#- module: system
#  period: 5m
#  metricsets:
#    - raid
```

Comment: This thread might help: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/metricbeat-system-filesystem-metrics-does-not-include-network-drives/165420/5

Comment: Thank you for your link, i understand now how it work.